# How to start Facebook app programatically?

Tags: android, facebook

i need to add a functionality on my app to start Facebook

Comment: Just in case you want to launch the facebook app directly, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191492/launch-facebook-app-from-other-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
intent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana", "com.facebook.katana.LoginActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

thanks alextsc