# How to navigate user to a facebook page via Android's facebook api?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [launch facebook app from other app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191492/launch-facebook-app-from-other-app)

Im a beginner with facebook api and i must say the documentation is very bad.
Now i can post to my wall from my app and add some content, but i just cant find anywhere on internet how to open facebook with the page i want.

Anyone can tell me how to do this?

Comment: You mean open "Pages" on Facebook? Add a few extra details which will help bring clarity to your question.

Comment: The Facebook documentation sometimes isn't clear, but it's quite comprehensive and I definitely wouldn't call it 'very bad'.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to open a specific page by giving FB page id within official facebook app for android, do something like this:

```
try {
      //try to open page in facebook native app.
      String uri = "fb://page/" + yourFBpageId;    //Cutsom URL
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
      startActivity(intent);   
}catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex){
      //facebook native app isn't available, use browser.
      String uri = "http://touch.facebook.com/pages/x/" + yourFBpageId;  //Normal URL  
      Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));    
      startActivity(i); 
}
```

complete URL scheme supported by fb app [can be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5707825/593709).

Comment: Works verry well, thank you man.