# Facebook link to be opened in app instead of browser

Tags: android, iphone, facebook, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [launch facebook app from other app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191492/launch-facebook-app-from-other-app)

I'm looking to see if it is possible to do the the following:

To have an email with a social link to a Facebook page within it, but, upon clicking, it won't open your phones browser but the official Facebook app.

Anyone know if that is possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use these options:

```
fb://profile – Open Facebook app to the user’s profile
fb://friends – Open Facebook app to the friends list
fb://notifications – Open Facebook app to the notifications list (NOTE: there appears to be a bug with this URL. The Notifications page opens. However, it’s not possible to navigate to anywhere else in the Facebook app)
fb://feed – Open Facebook app to the News Feed
fb://events – Open Facebook app to the Events page
fb://requests – Open Facebook app to the Requests list
fb://notes- Open Facebook app to the Notes page
fb://albums – - Open Facebook app to Photo Albums list
```

and many more.  As for android there may be something similar.  **It's possible the same URL's work for the newer versions of the Android FB app.  I have no device to check with.**

Comment: This is the correct answer but do note that some of those schemes are a pain in the ass and work very badly. There is no official documentation for this, so they can be unsupported in the future.

Comment: Indeed, but it is the only way to do it.

Comment: can you please look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45458995/open-facebook-page-into-facebook-application-ios-ionic