# Open facebook app from cordova/phonegap app

Tags: javascript, android, ios, facebook, cordova

I'm working on a cordova app. 
I'd like to open a facebook page programmatiacally using javascript and I want to open that page using the facebook app (if installed) in the system (Android, iOS).

I tried:

```
var ID = 1010101010000;
var full_URL = "https://www.facebook.com/pages/page_name/" + ID;

window.open(full_URL, '_system');             
window.open('fb:' + full_URL);
window.open('fb:' + 'https://www.facebook.com/' + ID);
window.open('https://www.facebook.com/' + ID, '_system');
```

but nothing works.

Can you help me?

Thanks

**edit**:

I tried: 
`window.open("facebook://pages/" + ID, '_system');` 
and similars, it just opens the facebook app but it does not redirect to the facebook page I want.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264225/facebook-link-to-be-opened-in-app-instead-of-browser

Comment: Ok thanks, for Android I need to use `facebook://` but I can't make it works anyway. Please see my edit.

Comment: did you got the solution for it??