# Open facebook page into facebook application Ios + ionic

Tags: ios, angularjs, facebook, ionic-framework

> **Goal :- Open facebook page url into facebook application**

I am using ionic `version 1.6` I have tried

```
<a ng-click="openFb()">   
    <img src="img/fb.png" alt="" width="auto" height="auto">
</a>
```

In controller file i have my function below.

```
$scope.openFb = function() {  
    window.open('fb://page/1372537532795807', "_system");
 };
```

Above after searching lot i have found that if you wants to open page you have to pass `fb:://page[page_id]` than  `fb:://profile/[page_id]`

But when i clicks on button nothing happens not even opening installed facebook application on my device.

Looking forward to have some help.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution: Add URL Schemes to the Whitelist**

Simply open your app's .plist (usually platforms/ios//-Info.plist) with an editor and add the following code with your needed Schemes.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fb</string>
</array>
```

Apple changed the canOpenURL method on iOS 9. Apps which are checking for URL Schemes on iOS 9 and iOS 10 have to declare these Schemes as it is submitted to Apple. The article [Quick Take on iOS 9 URL Scheme Changes](http://awkwardhare.com/post/121196006730/quick-take-on-ios-9-url-scheme-changes) expains the changes in detail.

**Reference link** :- https://github.com/ohh2ahh/AppAvailability/issues/22

Comment: Helped by @Ankur Akvaliya