# Facebook Android SDK - Send data to Facebook Application

Tags: android, facebook

I'm using Facebook SDK for Android to embedded Facebook inside my social app.

is there a way - from my Android app - to open the Facebook Application on a specific user's profile ?

Some kind of sending an Intent to the Facebook Application ?

My goal is to direct the user to its friend's profile in Facebook right from my application

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered in other stackoverflow posts such as this one:

[launch facebook app from other app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191492/launch-facebook-app-from-other-app)

I would like to remind developers that this is not officially supported so this may be broken anytime.  Using it for your own app is at your own risk.