# Calling G+ intent to check in?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-plus

I would like to put a 'check in' option in my app, which would uses at least Facebook and Google+, and now I have a problem - how to call their intents to do that?

For FB I found that:

```
String uri = "fb://places";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
startActivity(intent);
```

Where URI comes from that post:
[launch facebook app from other app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191492/launch-facebook-app-from-other-app)

But I have no idea for Google+, I looked into documentation (which is poor) and found nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to write to a user's Stream in any form, including for a check-in. However, you can and should make these feature requests in our Issue Tracker, which you can find at https://developers.google.com/+/support.  Also, it may be worth checking out the Developer Preview for Google+ History, which allows writing "moments." However, keep in mind that this is a developer preview, and not something you can currently build an app upon.