# Facebook request action

Tags: android, facebook, request

In my mobile application I open a [facebook requests dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) and send my friends some requests. How can I achieve the following behavior? When android user opens notifications bar of his smartphone and taps my request - my application (which sent it) should open (or market should open on my application's page). Now when user taps on my request a facebook application opens.

How can I set what happens when user taps my facebook request in the notifications menu? E.g. candy crash saga requests open the market on the CCS page. My requests open the facebook app.

Answer (score 1):

You mean you want to [Start Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) that you've written?

Or, you want to launch the Facebook app from your app. [Check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191492/launch-facebook-app-from-other-app).

Comment: I successfully send facebook requests from my android app to my friends. My friends successfully recieve requests. I want my application to be launched on my friend's device when he taps my facebook request in the notifications menu. Or I want the market to be opened instead. Now when friend taps facebook request the facebook application is launched.

Comment: Your friend receives the notice from Facebook, not your app.  You can't hijack Facebook's intent (how would you feel if other apps could do that to you? :D).  Best you could possibly do was have your app on your friends device scan his FB for requests you care about and submit your own notifications on his device.

Comment: CCS sends facebook requests and when user recieves them and taps on the recived request, the facebook application opens and automatically redirects to play market's page of CCS. I've just tested it again.