# How to open the search-for-friends page on facebook from an android app?

Tags: java, android, facebook

I have two questions:
1) Is there a way to open the search-page on facebook app from my android application?
2) If there is a way, can I open the activity with extras and tell facebook what to search?

I tried to find in the internet an answer, but I came with no success.

Comment: have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4191492/launch-facebook-app-from-other-app

Comment: It didn't help me. I can't find the search activity.

Comment: In second answer there he mentioned fb://search you can try whether that works or not. I haven't tried it.