# Deep link to a friend's wall in Facebook app (Android)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-intent

Starting with `Facebook` Graph API v2.0 [friend-ids are app-scoped](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids).

So how can I launch the `Facebook` info/wall page of a specific user's friend using the `"fb://"` scheme (as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6638342/819355) with an app-specific friend id?

Looking at Facebook's app manifest it seems they still register to the `"facebook://"` and `"fb://"` schemes, so I hope this is still somehow possible.

Comment: There is no official way to open a profile in the native app