# how to Launch Facebook app or Facebook Lite app on button click if installed otherwise open FB url?

Tags: android, kotlin

i want to launch Facebook app or Facebook Lite app on button click if installed otherwise open https://www.facebook.com/ url in browser.
i have a code to know apps installed or not in device but i am facing a problem to launch any app if available on button click. Please provide me any best solution without Facebook SDK integration.

```
private fun isFbAppInstalled():Boolean{
    try {
        val info = activity!!.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0)
        return true
    } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
        return false
    }

}
```

Comment: show us your code, let us see what you have tried

Comment: It's simple then, inside your `Buttons` click listener call this `isFbAppInstalled()` if it returns true open facebook via intent

Comment: that's the problem whose am facing am not able to launch fb app on click. it's show white screen only.
 if (isFbAppInstalled()){
                val intent = Intent("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
                intent.setClassName("com.facebook.katana", "com.facebook.katana.LoginActivity")
                startActivity(intent)
            }

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, tested now.

```
if (isFbAppInstalled()) {

    String uri = "facebook:/newsfeed";
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

- [List of available URIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6638342/3682535)
- [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4191847/3682535)